# GoogleSignIn-GoogleSignIn SDK not working when archiving build on Xcode 14.2

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

Facing below error while archiving build on Xcode 14.2

Error - Signing for "GoogleSignIn-GoogleSignIn" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.

I'm using this GoogleSignIn-GoogleSignIn SDK using pod.

What is the work around to resolve this signing issue without breaking anything for building with Xcode 13.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling code signing from the Podfile worked for me.

put this in your podfile            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO' & pod install.